# vim-fugitive: Netrw not found. Define your own :Browse to use :GBrowse

Tags: plugin-fugitive

`:GBrowse` is giving `Netrw not found. Define your own :Browse to use :GBrowse`  since `netrw` is disabled by `telescope.nvim`.

I tried to define `:Browse` like this:

```
:command! -nargs=1 Browse !open <args>
```

but it does not work properly when using `:GBrowse` with ranges like `:.GBrowse` or `:'<,'>GBrowse`, because the url will contain `#` and it will try to expand it to the alternate filename (`:h alternate-file`, `:h c_#`). The expansion fails with `E194: No alternate file name to substitute for '#': !open https://github.com/xxx/yyy#L3`

How can I define a `:Browse` that works for `:GBrowse` in all cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following `:Browse` definition works when using `:GBrowse` with ranges:

```
:command! -nargs=1 Browse silent execute '!open' shellescape(<q-args>,1)
```

Relevant help pages: `:h :!`, `:h shellescape()`, `:h :execute` and `:h :silent`)

Answer (score 3):

For those who want a pure Lua solution in neovim, here is a Lua version of @RubenLaguna solution:

```lua
vim.api.nvim_create_user_command(
  'Browse',
  function (opts)
    vim.fn.system { 'xdg-open', opts.fargs[1] }
  end,
  { nargs = 1 }
)
```

Using `xdg-open` as the external command will work with most Linux distributions. Mac OS users use `open` instead and Windows users would use `start` to achieve the same.